# Find element with matching attribute

Tags: jquery, xml

I have some xml:

```
<myco:results xmlns:myco="http://myco.mycollp.com" resultsTypeID="StockChart">
    <myco:row xmlns:myco="http://myco.mycollp.com">
        <myco:price title="stock">0.6107013847</myco:price>
        <myco:price title="index">0.61965464</myco:price>
    </myco:row>
</myco:results>
```

I am looping over it using the following jQuery:

```
$(xml).find("row").each(function () {

    var stockPrice = $(this).find("price[title='stock']").text();
}
```

However stockPrice is always coming back as an empty string.

if I inspect:

```
$(this).find("price[title!='stock']")
```

it has a length of 2, not 1, and

```
$(this).find("price[title='stock']")
```

has a length of 0.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Have given full xml with namespace info, I had omitted this originally to make the example clearer but this may be the cause of the problem so have give the full XML now.

Comment: And I assume `$(this).find("price[title='stock']")` length is zero?

Comment: Works: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/cV8pb/.

Comment: @pimvdb: I get no alerts when I run it, but no js errors either. IE8.

Comment: @Justin Satyr: You're correct, I'm checking it and it appears that it does work on IE9 but not on IE8. Not sure what's the reason behind that.

Comment: @pimvb: I've updated to give the full xml above and at http://jsfiddle.net/openshac/PvakT/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I managed to work it using the jsfiddle.net website that @pimvdb suggested.

```
var xml = '<myco:results xmlns:myco="http://myco.mycollp.com">\
    <myco:row xmlns:myco="http://myco.mycollp.com">\
        <myco:price title="stock">0.61</myco:price>\
        <myco:price title="index">12.5</myco:price>\
            </myco:row>\
</<myco:results>';

$(xml).find("myco\\:row").each(function () {
    var stockPrice = $(this).find("myco\\:price[title='stock']").text();
    alert(stockPrice);
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

here it is your selectors were incorrect while using a namespace:
http://jsfiddle.net/PvakT/3/